# How to create .txt file on remote server using ftplib and place some string in it using a variable?

Tags: python, io, ftp, ftplib

I have a function to create a file on remote server and I want to fill that file with an Entry (input field). My question is, when i use this code;

```
def createFileRemote():
    textToWrite = io.StringIO(create_file_remote_input_text.get())
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+create_file_remote_filename.get(),textToWrite)
```

I got an error says,

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I tried something like this;

```
textToWrite = io.BytesIO(b""+create_file_remote_input_text.get())
```

but it does not concatenate str with bytes. Any suggestion ? I want to give textToWrite from an input field. It's working when i give it from code like this;

```
io.BytesIO(b"Some text")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this solves it

```
def createFileRemote():
    to_bytes = bytes(create_file_remote_input_text.get(), "UTF-8")
    textToWrite = io.BytesIO(to_bytes)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+create_file_remote_filename.get(),textToWrite)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed this code a bit and it worked 
 to_bytes = bytes(create_file_remote_input_text.get(), "UTF-8")
 textToWrite = io.BytesIO(to_bytes)